# Laravel 5.2 : "return redirect()" not working properly inside Custom Event Handlers

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication, event-handling, laravel-5

In Laravel `5.2`, i have my **Custom** Event Handler (for Login Event). Like this:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => ['App\Listeners\UserLoggedIn'],
];
```

There's the `handle` function in `app/Listeners/UserLoggedIn.php`:

```
public function handle(Login $event)
{
    /**
     * Some codes here
     */

    if ( $foo==$bar ) {
        //echo "I was here!";
        //exit;

        return redirect('mypage');
    }

}
```

The `mypage` route is defined properly and it can be called manually via url. (And it runs). So the `mypage` route has no problem.

When the Event is triggered, everything works except `return redirect('mypage');` even when the process falls into the `IF` condition. (And then **the process continues to call the home (default) route**, instead of `mypage` route.)

Any idea please?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797930/laravel-redirect-does-not-work-in-event-handler-listener

Comment: That 'response' is never making it out of the application, it is just a value returned from that handler. It would have to then be returned from something else in the pipeline at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a best solution but i've found a workaround which works, at least. I cannot use Laravel's `redirect()` in Handler(s), but instead use the PHP native redirection and then force to exit from the function.

Like:

```
header("location: /mypage");
return;
```

At least it allows me to stop the function at where it is supposed to, and then let me go to where i need.